# How to show different error messages when entering repeated data to the database? Php / MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying that, when the user enters the name of a region, if the same one is repeated it is shown in screen "It happened an error", but I can not do it.
Region.php:

```
class Region
{
    private $regID;
    private $regName;

    private function loadData()
    {

          if(isset($_POST["regID"]))
          {
              $this->setRegID($_POST["regID"]);
          }

          if(isset($_POST["regName"]))
          {
              $this->setRegNombre($_POST["regName"]);
          }
     }

       public function addRegion()
       {
            $this->loadData();

            $link = Connection::connect();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO regions(regName) VALUES (:regName)";

            $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

            $regName = $this->getRegName();

            $stmt->bindParam(":regName",$regName,PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute())
            { 
                return true;
            }
          return false;
       }
}
```

AddRegion.php:

```
<?php 
   require "class/Connection.php";
   require "class/Region.php";

     $objRegion = new Region();

      $objRegion->addRegion();

     if($objRegion){
 ?>
         <p>Added region</p>

    <?php }else{ ?>

      <p>An error occurred.</p>

          <?php /*if('error code==666'){ //With the error code show this:
                     <p>There is already a region with that name.</p>
                   }*/?>


  <?php } ?>
```

But what I see on the screen is the following:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'America' for key 'regName' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\class\Region.php on line 60
>
> Added region

- How can I make the error message not be shown?
- How can I do so that if there is an error, Region Added does not appear,but "Did an error occurred" be shown on screen?
- And how can I know from the MySQL error code if the error is that the name is repeated?

Answer (score 0):

You got the error message because it is likely that your database schema in table regions defined regName as UNIQUE. So review your database schema design.

Use `try..catch` block to catch the `PDOException`.

```
try {
    $objRegion->addRegion();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    $existingkey = "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry";
    if (strpos($e->getMessage(), $existingkey) !== FALSE) {

        // here goes is your duplicate data error
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

This example is taken from [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) which is is worth of reading to give you a good understanding on proper use of PDO in PHP.

Comment: Why the down voting? I appreciated the edition, but why delete my entire paragraph? I'm trying to point out the root cause of error, the field maybe not need to be UNIQUE. If you have different opinions or think it is wrong, add your comment.

Comment: why should he review the schema, if that's his purpose to disallow duplicated data?

Comment: This is much better, I appreciated the comment and you may have a valid point, but I prefer for me to decide whether to delete my paragraph or not. BTW, you have my full respect on your masterpiece of  (The only proper) PDO tutorial, I read it and refer to it as a valuable reference.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the response!
Yes,the idea is that regName is setted as UNIQUE.
I solved my problem,i used try/catch.
But your link helped me a lot.
The problem was that in my db connection class i didn´t setted PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
so,i couldn´t catch the exceptions.
Thanks for your help!